# Undefined index on laravel8

Tags: php, api, laravel-8

I'm learning to display public API data from http://batikita.herokuapp.com/index.php/batik/all

I have tried to display data with the following syntax:

InfoController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class InfoController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $response = Http::get('http://batikita.herokuapp.com/index.php/batik/all');
        $data = $response->json();
        return view('index', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Appearance</th>
                <th scope="col">Batik Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Origin</th>
                <th scope="col">History</th>
                <th scope="col">Lowest Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Highest Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php
                    $no = 0;
                @endphp
                @foreach ($data as $dataBatik)
                    @php
                        $no++;
                    @endphp
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ $no }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['link_batik'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['nama_batik'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['daerah_batik'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['makna_batik'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['harga_rendah'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $dataBatik['hasil']['harga_tinggi'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWJt5.png)

What is the correct syntax for displaying data from the public API with laravel8? Please help, thank you.

Comment: In your controller return `$data` instead of the view, just to know what is inside the `$data`. It will give you the hint on how to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error doesn't actually have something to do with Laravel, just some basic php.

You should loop on `$data['hasil']` and display information like `$dataBatik['link_batik']`.

```php
@foreach ($data['hasil'] as $dataBatik)
    ...
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $no }}</th>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['link_batik'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['nama_batik'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['daerah_batik'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['makna_batik'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['harga_rendah'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $dataBatik['harga_tinggi'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

As you foreach loop you can use as this

```
 @foreach($data as $dataBatik)
    {{ $dataBatik['link_batik'] }}
 @endforeach
```